# Uniform Distribution - Finding probability distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given the random variable X has a uniform distribution

$$f(x) = 1$$  $$\text{if }1<x<2$$

Find the probability distribution of the random variable:  $$Y = -2\ln x$$

Could you anyone please help me in understanding how to solve the given problem, I don't know if I should be using PDF or CDF in the given problem, I have searched a lot for similar problems but I can't seem to find any and I got really confused with this one!

Comment: You're given the PDF for $X$.  Can you write down its CDF?  If so, does that tell you anything about the CDF of $Y$?

Comment: I have found the CDF for X and it is == to **x-1**, so I am not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Okay, so when $1 < x < 2$, the probability that $X < x$ is $x-1$.  Can you use this to calculate the probability that $Y < y$ for some number $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets consider the situation where we use the PDF. We know:

$$f_X(x)=1,\space y=-2\ln x \implies x=e^{-\frac y2}$$

Lets take the derivative with respect to $y$:

$$\frac {dx}{dy}=-\frac 12e^{-\frac y2}$$

Under the inverse transform method, we can use the fact that:

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(y) \left| \frac {dx}{dy} \right|$$
$$=f_X(-2 \ln x)\left|-\frac 12e^{-\frac y2} \right|$$
$$=1\cdot \frac 12e^{-\frac y2}$$
$$=\frac 12e^{-\frac y2}$$

The only part left is to find our bounds for the random variable $Y$.

From the equation $y=-2\ln x$:

$$x=1 \implies y=-2 \ln 1=0$$
$$x=2 \implies y=-2 \ln 2$$

We can check the density of $Y$ integrates to $1$:

$$\int_{-2 \ln 2}^0f_Y(y)dy=\int_{-2 \ln 2}^0\frac 12e^{-\frac y2}dy$$

$$=\left[-e^{- \frac y2}\right]_{-2 \ln 2}^0=-1-(-2)=1$$

Comment: Could you elaborate more please, I want to see this example as solved so I can work on similar problems further. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sure! I will go on to solve it. But if you want to check out some other examples, have a look at the link. It goes into a bit more detail than I will. http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf