# Show that for $i=1,..,n, \ X^2_i\sim \text{Gamma}(1,\frac{1}{\pi\lambda})$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, gamma-distribution

> Consider a random sample $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ from a variable with density function $$f_X(x)=2\lambda\pi xe^{-\lambda\pi x^2}, \quad x\geq 0$$
>   I am trying to show that for  $i=1,..,n,\  X^2_i\sim  \text{Gamma}(1,\frac{1}{\pi\lambda})$

Now I don't really know where to begin with this question. I'm not even sure what $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X^2_i$ equals. Apologies for not including an attempt, this question has stumped me.

**Attempt:**

We want to find $f_Y(y)$ where $Y=X^2$.

First we note that $y=x^2$ is monotonic over $x>0$

Hence 
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y)&=f_X(y)\Big|\frac{dx}{dy}\Big| \\
&=2\lambda\pi\sqrt{y}e^{-\lambda\pi y} \Big|\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\Big| \\
&=\lambda\pi e^{-\lambda\pi y} \ \ \ \ \ y>0
\end{align*}
Since $Y_i\sim \text{Gamma}(1,\frac{1}{\pi\lambda})$, we can see that $X^2_i\sim \text{Gamma}(1,\frac{1}{\pi\lambda})$

Comment: Do you know about Jacobians? Transforms of random variables? Inverse transform method?

Comment: I do know of Jacobians and a little of the transformations of random variables. If you could give me some hints of how to solve this problem, I'd really appreciate it. I'd like to put up an attempted solution to avoid further downvotes

Comment: You may find it better to read up on the methods available on transformations of random variables. It will give you a better understanding of how to apply them in general! There are plenty of ways to tackle this problem, [this](http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf) will give you a good understanding with examples. On the other hand, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805001/uniform-distribution-finding-probability-distribution-of-a-random-variable/2805003#2805003) is a similar question with a worked example.

Comment: Why does this have so many downvotes?

Comment: Thank you for the link, I had a good read but the most important thing was understanding the question. I wasn't completely confident in what the question was asking for, but not I think I do. Is the logic in my attempt above correct?

Comment: @Prime: please feel free to upvote hahah perhaps it was because I did not initially have a solution

Comment: +1 for the attempt lol

Comment: Why don't you try computing $P(X_i^2<t)=P(X_i<\sqrt t) ?$

Comment: I guess I could try this. But I have already produced a solution and I  would like to know if it is valid.